# External regressor rugarch

Tags: r, time-series, arima, garch

Consider a ARMA$(p,q)$ model of $y$ with $m$ external regressors $x_1, ..., x_m$. Do I understand the documentation of the R package [rugarch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf) correct, that the considered model is of the form
$$y(t):=\mu + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}a_i y(t-i)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{q}b_i\varepsilon(t-i)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}c_ix_i(t)+\varepsilon(t),$$
where $\mu$ is the offset, $a_i, b_i, c_i$ are coefficients and $\varepsilon(t)$ is white noise? Consequently, the argument `external.regressors` in the function `autoarfima` of `rugarch` includes the external regressors $x_1, ..., x_m$ as described by the equation above?

Comment: Can you add to the post the model call?

Comment: Please add that as an edit to the post, as comments on this site are often overlooked and can be removed!

Comment: `n <- 1000  
y <- rnorm(n)  
x <- cbind(rnorm(n), rnorm(n))  
spec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2,1), include.mean = TRUE, external.regressors = x),  variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), distribution.model = "norm")  
fit <- ugarchfit(spec, data = y, solver = "hybrid")`

I added two spaces at each end of the line to include a line space, however it does not work.